# JS : Search partially an item form an items list object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter

i have a list object which i load from a web service , my list comes in this form :

```
list = { "name1 Surname1" , "name2" , "name3Surname3" , "surname4" }
```

as you can see i have different formats :

separated name-surname with space , only name , only surname .

My purpose is to search member by name or surname ; my result should be apart of one of the list members .

**For example :**

- If i search for : "name1"  -> **result** : name1 Surname1
- If i search for : "name1 Surn" -> **result** : name1 Surname1
- If i search for : "name1 SurAAA" -> **result** : (nothing)
- If i search for : "AAAA Surname1" -> **result** : (nothing)
- If i search for : "name1Surname1" -> **result** : (nothing)
- If i search for : "name" -> **result** : name1 Surname1 , name2 , name3Surname3 , surname4

***To summarize :***

i should search items:

- corresponding for my searched item
- beginning with my searched item

I have tried the **filter** solution , like the following :

```
findItems(name) {
      this.splits = name.toLowerCase().split(' ');
      if (this.splits.length >= 1) {
        results = this.namesList.filter(item => this.splits.indexOf(item.brand.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
      }else {
        results = [];
      }
  }
```

But this solution is only searching for items corresponding **exactly** to my searched item , and it lacks the **partial search**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: please add some data, the search string and the wanted result as well.

Comment: is `list` an `object` or `array`?

Comment: It s a List of names not an array

Comment: I'm not following. It's either an `array` or it is an `object`. Your `list` as you have it now is not valid `json` or `array` syntax. That shouldn't even run.

Comment: @JohanP : it"s a list of strings

Comment: The way that you have list with the {} is not valid syntax, it is missing keys. Should list not be with [] rather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` and `RegExp()` to complete this. Keep in mind, this will return an `array` of all matching results:

```js
let list = [ 'name1 Surname1' , 'name2' , 'name3Surname3' , 'surname4' ];

function findItems(name) {
     return list.filter(item => {
    const regex = new RegExp(name, 'gi');
    return item.match(regex);
  });
  }
  
console.log(findItems('name1 s')); // outputs ["name1 Surname1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution if your name is in a list instead of an object

```js
list = [ "name1 Surname1" , "name2" , "name3Surname3" , "surname4" ]


function findItems(searchedName, nameList) {
      return nameList.map((nameString) => {
      if(nameString.includes(searchedName))
          return nameString;
      });
}
  
console.log(findItems("name", list))
```